# Drawer Opened instead of going back

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have an app which utilized NavigationDrawer and toolbar. When I click on one of the menu in the NavigationDrawer, it displays a fragment (let's call it fragment1). Inside fragment1 is a button, when clicked would display another fragment (fragment2).

Ok so when I'm at fragment1, the toolbar would display a hamburger icon, where when I click on it, the drawer would be opened. And when I'm at fragment2, the toolbar would display a back icon (up caret) instead of the hamburger. Ok this is correct, but when I click on the back icon (up caret) the drawer would be opened instead. So what should I do so that when the back icon (up caret) is clicked, I'd be brought back to fragment1, and not opening the drawer?

This is my onClick for the drawer

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getPosition();
            Fragment fragment = null;
            FragmentManager fManager = ((FragmentActivity) contxt).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
            Toast.makeText(contxt, "The Item Clicked isss: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) ((FragmentActivity) contxt).findViewById(R.id.dlMainDrawer);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    fragment = new MenuHome(); 
                    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentHome");
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new MenuExpensesDaily(); 
                    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentExpensesDaily");
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

So using the code above, I opened an instance of MenuExpensesDaily. And inside MenuExpensesDaily, when I click on a menu item, it would open another fragment, ExpensesDailyAdd, as shown below:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem mItem = menu.findItem(R.id.tbAddExpenses);
        mItem.setVisible(true);
        mItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                ExpensesDailyAdd addExpenses = new ExpensesDailyAdd();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, addExpenses, null)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Ok so now when ExpensesDailyAdd is opened, the hamburger icon is changed to the up caret. But when I click the up caret, it opens the drawer instead of going back to the previous fragment.

Comment: show us some of your code..

Comment: @Rahil2952 duly complied